# Apply function usage in Python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe called df and I have to apply a function called fn to it. I tried the below 2 methods. Both of them are fetching me the same results, but I want to know the difference between them.

```py
df = df.apply(fn)

df = df.apply(lambda x : fn(x))
```

Please tell me what's the difference in these two lines.

Comment: There is no difference, except that in the second case `apply()` calls the `lambda` that calls `fn()`, so you add one level to your call stack.

Comment: Well, in one you use `fn` directly, in the other, you create and use a pointless function with your lambda expression, that simply calls `fn`

Comment: if `foo = lambda x : fn(x)` then it is equivalent to `foo=fn` the later one is unnecessary if you have the function already.

Comment: `lambda x: fn(x)` is just a wrapper for `fn`.  It serves no purpose.  It's an anonymous version of `def func(x): return fn(x)`.

Comment: @Epsi95 It's functionally equivalent, but it does more work.  The lamba isn't an alias, it's a wrapper, with the overhead of a wrapper.  Also, your example suggests `foo == fn` would be `True`.  It won't.  So there are several differences.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no big difference.
In the first example, you are passing the function directly to the `apply()` method and the method will then use the passed instance to call the **fn** function for each data.
In the second example you are creating something called an anonymous function (lambda function) which is just a one-line function for simple purposes. The second example will be equivalent to the code-snippet below if you weren't using *lambda* functions.

```py
def lmbda(x):
    return fn(x)

df.apply(lmbda)
```

Comment: Lambda *expression*; both lambda expressions and `def` statements create the same type of value, namely values of type `function`.